# Chance of... consecutive events

Tags: probability

I'm calculating probabilities for a game but I am uncertain about my calculations.

In the game, you're able to draw cards ($10$ cards in a row each time). Each time you draw a card you have a certain % chance to draw a card, like:
$2$ of spades: $12\%$, $4$ of spades: $14\%$ and so on...

You can draw the same card over and over, so we can consider infinite cards, drawing a 2 of spades three times in a row will not change any probability (still 12%).

I'm trying to know what are my chances to get at least one of each during 10 draws.

This is what I think it would be:
$1-((1-$probability$)$^$10)$

Why I did that:

"1-probability" equals the chance of NOT obtaining the card.
"^$10$" for $10$ consecutive draws
That would give me the chances of not obtaining the card on any of those 10 draws.
So, $1$ minus that value would give me the probability of obtaining at least one of the card...

Am I right, or did I miss something?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "...get at least one of **each** during 10 draws."

Comment: I mean i'm calculating it for all of them, but not at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Your ^$10$ would only work if there were two cards you were dealing with. To calculate the probability, you need to calculate the chance of all the remaining cards. I am assuming the total possible types cards are 10, as your "one of each" implies. If we let $P_{ace},P_{2},...P_{10}$ be the probabilities of drawing the respective card, we can derive the following:

Probability of getting a specific card at a draw (of ten cards): $$P=1-(1-P_{card})^{10}$$
Probability of getting all 10 card types at a draw in a specific order (of ten cards): $$P=P_{ace}\cdot P_{2}\cdot P_{3}\cdot...\cdot P_{10}$$

Probability of getting all 10 card types at a draw in any order (of ten cards):
$$P=(P_{ace}\cdot P_{2}\cdot P_{3}\cdot...\cdot P_{10})\cdot10!$$
The $10!$ (or $10⋅9⋅8⋅...⋅2⋅1$) represents the $3,628,800$ rearrangements the $10$ unique cards you draw can be in.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, i see...
Thanks, it did help!